# Increasing available area of a solid will increase effective concentration?

Tags: concentration

If I say that making a solid reactant into a powder will increase the yield of the product, because it increases the available area of the solid, hence increasing its effective concentration. Is this claim valid?

Comment: It will increase the rate of reaction. What affect that has on the yield depends on what you're making and how.

Comment: Doesn't it effectively increase concentration?

Comment: I don't think so. If we're talking about yield, then to predict the equilibrium constant, "concentration" should really be thermodynamic activity, and the activity of a solid is usually 1.

Answer (score 1):

The concentration of solid in itself is always the same, like **m3wolf** said in the comments (unless the solid is not pure, which is not relevant anyway, because grinding wouldn't change that either). So **no, you can't** change the effective concentration this way.

If anything, you will have higher *surface area* and hence higher *overall rate* of reaction (or dissolution, if the reaction happens in the solution and not on the surface, and thus has to be preceded by dissolution). In this manner, you will get the same yield, but in less time.

Secondary effects can eventually change your yield in an unpredictable way, as likely down as up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a solid *hypothesis* that will *probably* prove to be true.  I mainly base that on the likelihood that more solid reactant will be available to react.  Also, think about the statement in reverse:
"Compressing my finely powdered solid reactant into a single hard clump should increase the yield of my reaction."
Sounds unlikely.

However, I have made some assumptions in saying the *hypothesis* is probably true.  What if the other reactant is a liquid that thoroughly penetrates the unground solid and is able to react with all of the solid this way?  Then what if the reaction gives better yields when it proceeds slowly?  What if it's highly exothermic and the powdered solid reacts so fast it blows all over the lab?

Of course you can control the rate of reactant addition, cool the reaction, etc. to mitigate these things, but these are just some examples of what could go wrong with the seemingly obvious "true" answer I proposed above.  Still, I am confident your claim will be valid more often than not.